# LAPACKE eigen solution is inaccurate. How to improve it?

Tags: c++, lapack

I am in need of a C eigenproblem solver under Ubuntu. To this end I gave LAPACKE from lapack 3.5.0 a shot and actually managed to write the lower example program which's
example I constructed from the orthogonal system and diagonal matrix

```
EV = [
  .6, -.8, 0
  .8,  .6, 0
   0,   0, 1
];
D = [
  2,  0, 0
  0, -3, 0
  0,  0, 0
];
```

by producing A := EV D EV'.

While the lower program runs okay the results are strangely inaccurate.
Here the end of the output:

```
...
Lambda: -3.07386, 0, 1.87386
EV = [
  -0.788205        0       -0.615412
   0.615412        0       -0.788205
  -0               1        0
];
Info: 0
```

As documentation I used [www.physics.orst.edu/~rubin/nacphy/lapack/routines/dsyev.html](http://www.physics.orst.edu/~rubin/nacphy/lapack/routines/dsyev.html)

My complete source:

```
/**
 * eigen.cpp
 * 
 * Given that you put version 3.5.0 into /opt/lapack/ compile this with: 
 * g++ eigen.cpp -I"/opt/lapack/lapack-3.5.0/lapacke/include" \
     -L"/opt/lapack/lapack-3.5.0" -llapacke -llapack -lblas -lcblas
 * The order of included libraries is important!
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
// cstdlib needs including before clapack!
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cblas.h>
#include <lapacke.h>

using namespace std;

/** Column major style! */
string matrix2string(int m, int n, const double* A)
{
  ostringstream oss;
  for (int j=0;j<m;j++)
  {
    for (int k=0;k<n;k++)
    {
      oss << A[j+k*m] << "\t";
    }
    oss << endl;
  }
  return oss.str();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  //> Preliminaries. -------------------------------------------------
  // Column Major Matrices for setting up the problem.
  double D_orig[9] = {
    2,  0, 0,
    0, -3, 0,
    0,  0, 0
  };
  double EV_orig[9] = {
    3./5., 4./5., 0,
    -4./5., 3./5., 0,
    0, 0, 1
  };
  double A[9] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 };
  double dummy[9] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 };
  // A = EV D EV'
  // dummy := D EV'
  // A := EV dummy
  cblas_dgemm(CblasColMajor,CblasNoTrans,CblasTrans,3,3,3,1,&D_orig[0],3,&EV_orig[0],3,0,&dummy[0],3);
  cblas_dgemm(CblasColMajor,CblasNoTrans,CblasNoTrans,3,3,3,1,&EV_orig[0],3,&dummy[0],3,0,&A[0],3);
  cout << "Set up the problem building A = EV D EV'" << endl <<
    "EV = [" << endl << matrix2string(3,3,&EV_orig[0]).c_str() << "];" << endl <<
     "D = [" << endl << matrix2string(3,3,&D_orig[0]).c_str() << "];" << endl <<
     "A = [" << endl << matrix2string(3,3,&A[0]).c_str() << "];" << endl;
  //< ----------------------------------------------------------------
  //> Actual eigen value problem. ------------------------------------
  char jobz = 'V'; // We want both vectors and values.
  char uplo = 'L'; // 'L' means lower triangular input A as opposed to 'U'.
  int N = 3; // Matrix dimension, or as they call it, 'order'.
  // As stated by example ATriL is unnecessary. Just replace all of its
  // occurences with plain A and all is well.
  double ATriL[9] = { A[0], A[1], A[2], A[4], A[5], A[8], 0, 0, 0 }; // Lower Triangle of symmetric A.
    // Note that it is larger than necessary. It will contain the eigenvectors at the end.
  int lda = 3;
  double w[3] = { 0, 0, 0 }; // Container for the eigenvalues.
  int lwork = 15; // Size of the worker array. Set to (NB+2)*N where NB here is the largest blocksize.
    // Note, however, that the definition of NB is more complex.
    // Compare http://ftp.mcs.anl.gov/pub/MINPACK-2/lapack/ilaenv.f
  double work[lwork];
  int info = 0;

  // "double symmetric eigenvalue problem" I presume.
  // lapack_int LAPACKE_dsyev( int matrix_order, char jobz, char uplo, lapack_int n,
  //                           double* a, lapack_int lda, double* w );
  info = LAPACKE_dsyev(LAPACK_COL_MAJOR, jobz, uplo, N, &ATriL[0], lda, &work[0]);
  // Note that the function takes no parameters lwork and w and that the
  // eigenvalues appear to be written into work.
  cout << "Ran dsyev(..) -- presumably 'double symmetric eigenvalue'." << endl <<
    "Lambda: " << work[0] << ", " << work[1] << ", " << work[2] << endl <<
    "EV = [" << endl << matrix2string(3,3,&ATriL[0]) << "];" << endl <<
    "Info: " << info << endl;
  //< ----------------------------------------------------------------
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Finally the actual questions: Why are the results so inaccurate and what can I do to improve them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The results are exact - for the data that you gave to lapack. Unfortunately you did not solve the question that you wanted to.

The part with lower vs upper triangular part is only for some other (internal?) algorithms. In your simple case you don't need to worry about that. If you pass your matrix `A` instead of `ATril` you should be fine.

In more detail:
You are building `double ATriL[9]` such that it appears as

```
A[0], A[4], 0, 
A[1], A[5], 0, 
A[2], A[8], 0
```

to lapack. When you now tell it to use the lower triangular part of this matrix as symmetric input (`char uplo = 'L';`), lapack will effectively see the matrix

```
A[0], A[1], A[2],        -1.2 2.4 0
A[1], A[5], A[8],   ==    2.4 0   0
A[2], A[8], 0             0   0   0
```

whose eigenvectors actually are the ones that you got.

Comment: I see... I already felt some consternation to the fact that I would have to introduce some functions just for converting triangular matrices into quadratic symmetric versions and vice versa as needed by the various functions. It would appear I misunderstood the argument descriptions. Now I simply removed ATriL from my program, replaced its occurances with plain A and, as you predicted, was fine. Thanks a lot!